# Why is this edit rejected by community?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, community

A couple of minutes ago I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142224/php-mysql-form-submission-error) and thought it could use an edit because there was a lot of 'normal text' in the code blocks. However when I suggested the edit in which I removed the text out of the code block it was rejected by [community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) within a minute ([the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1968099)). Since the normal text was still in the code block after a couple of minutes I tried to edit it again [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1968129), as you can see the edit is approved by 2 users but then again the [community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) comes and rejects it for no reason.

Does anyone know what could be the reason for the 'community' to reject my edit?

Comment: In your case the OP most likely edited his post within the 5 minutes grace period, which isn't recorded anywhere. Better wait five minutes before editing.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd As you can see my second edit was 9minutes after the question was asked and it still wasn't edited.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Removed my comment. I glanced over the fact that that statement came from the initial code block.

Comment: Yeah you are right, something is going on here. The community user is on [rejection rampage](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=reviews).